# Add CSS attribute to certain span that contain a CSS style using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I have something like this

```
<span style="font-size: 1.7px; letter-spacing: -1.7px; color: #edf6fc">text</span>
```

and

```
<span style="font-size: 99.81%; color: #080007">text </span>
```

How would I select the first one and add; let's say `display: none` to its style (or remove that span) but not the second one using JavaScript.

Or how do I remove all the span that has CSS property `letter-spacing`?

Comment: You can use jquery/javascript selectors to select element and add your style.

Comment: with css selectors you can use 'span:nth-child(2)' but you're almost always better off using a class or ID for this

Comment: @Arun_C_C how do I select the first type of span but not the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `class` or `id` to those elements.

```
.spanOne{
    display: none;
}
```

**or**

create those elements dynamically and store them in variables.
Then you can use those variables to add or remove properties.

```
var spanOne = //code to create span element;
var spanTwo = //code to create another span element;

$(spanOne).hide();
```

**or**

```
$('#parentElementID').children('span').eq(0).hide();
```

**UPDATED**:

```
$('div').children('span').filter(function () {
    return this.style.fontSize == "17.7px";  //in your case 1.7px
}).eq(0).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
```

PS: I recommend adding a class name or id to that element.

Comment: I came cross a website like this. I can't assign a class or id for those span without knowing how to select it.

Comment: @TuanAnhTran then add those elements dynamically, as I shown in my answer.

Comment: they both have the same parent div.

Comment: @TuanAnhTran then you need to check a unique css property value. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/RaB67/1/

Comment: Thank you. I saw you use style.fontSize and did a quick search, there is a DOM style attrib for letterSpacing as well.

It works.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to add a `class` name or `id`:

```
<span id="iHateYou" style="font-size: 1.7px; letter-spacing: -1.7px; color: #edf6fc">text</span>
<span style="font-size: 99.81%; color: #080007">text </span>
```

and the js:

```
document.getElementById('iHateYou').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an add on like Firebug for example in Firefox, right click on the tag in issue, like here `<span>` then select inspect element. Go to the code and find out its parent with a unique identifier (ID), select that parent id and add CSS by parent child selection.

## For Instance,

```
#abc span{display: none;}
```

Add this in your stylesheet. This will make the child of the unique identifier to attach your style and override that one that is applying to it.